# Why I can't click but can right click with Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USyX4.png)I specified the button class in CSS selector and right click executed.
Then options displayed on the button, so it assure that the correct element position has been acquired.

## javascript

```
        .then(function () {
            var element = driver.findElement(By.className('xxx'))
            return element;
        })
        .then(function (element) {
            var action = new webdriver.ActionSequence(driver)
            action.click(element, webdriver.Button.RIGHT).perform()
        })
```

Problem arises when just click is executed, instead of right click.

```
        .then(function (element) {
            var action = new webdriver.ActionSequence(driver)
            action.click(element).perform()
        })
```

I hope the event when the button is pressed to be executed, but it doesn't. I cannot find any error message. I really don't know why...

## html

```
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-play">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true">
    </span>
      " play "
  </button>
```

I tried to select each class and result was same.

[button before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USyX4.png)
[button after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Nr0E.png)

Comment: Can you provide the HTML code you are trying this on? normally if the element is not clickable, not error is thrown. But with this much cant assure anything. Provide the HTML where this is being executed

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I added html code above.

Comment: I can see that aira-hidden="true", so do check first if the element is visible or not, if the element is not visible it cannot be clicked. 

Once that is checked I assume its a normal button, if normal click is not working try with javascriptExecutor where you can pass the javascript code to click. Try with these approaches and let me know what happened.

Comment: I added `driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(element), 10000)` after I had selected the element.
With "btn btn-default btn-play", nothing has changed.
With "glyphicon glyphicon-play", this error came out.      _TimeoutError: Waiting until element is visible
Wait timed out after 10002ms_

Comment: Ok this means the element is not visible and hence you cannot click. If you still want to force a click you need the change the attribute of aria-hidden to false and then click. If you need assistance in that let me know.

PS:to the change the attribute you need to execute script.

Comment: I tried ```driver.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-default btn-play').setAttribute('area-hidden', 'false')");```. But this error showed up _unknown error: document.getElementsByClassName(...).setAttribute is not a function_  .
I would really appreciate if you are still gonna help me.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-default btn-play')` will return array so try to do `document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-default btn-play')[*whatever index for element*].setAttribute('area-hidden', 'false')")`

Comment: ```driver.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('glyphicon glyphicon-play')[0].setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'false')")```
Thanks! It was confirmed that it changed to false. But, still can't click button.  ```var action = new webdriver.ActionSequence(driver)```
```action.click(element).perform()``` Though mouseover effect came out on button, but it doesn't work and never came off. What's wrong with this?

Comment: Can you click on it manually? if you cant then the webdriver also cannot click on it. it would ge helpful if u could give me the url that u r trying to perform this action on

Comment: Sorry, that page belongs our company, but I added links to button image above. When it is mouseovered, its color changes from white to grey. This image is when using Selenium, but  same when manually. When color is grey, I can click it manually and some action started, but with Selenium, just color changed and nothing happened.

Comment: ok one more approach could be, try to run the click via javascript in the developer console manually and check if the actions are triggered and if yes then after setting the aria-hidden to false, perform javascript click... let me knw if this works

Comment: ```driver.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-default btn-play')[0].click()")```
This worked! Even if aria-hidden is true. So maybe I've tried to click in wrong way. Anyway, you really saved me, thank you so much!

Comment: if this actually worked then ill go ahead and post this answer? might help other people.. easy to check rather than go through these burried comments.

Comment: Technically, it may have worked regardless of aria-hidden. But, thanks anyway!

Comment: yes but u cannot click via selenium if its hidden... but the js click would have gone through anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I must have been confused... Now I got what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `aria-hidden="true"` you can achieve this by directly clicking using javascript. :)

```
driver.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-default btn-play')[0].click()")
```